# Get values from string through RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get `size` values from a strings, which looks like:
`https://example.com/eb5f16e5-9b3d-cfcd-19b0-75c6ace724e1/size/80x90/center/`

I'm using `match` method and following RegEx:
`'...'.match(/\/(\d+)x(\d+)\//g)`

I hoped that the parentheses help to highlight the numbers:
[image: RegEx]

But `match` returns only `["/80x90/"]` without separate size values, like `["/80x90/", "80", "90"]`.
What am I'm doing wrong?

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/lKpn6k/2/) you can test my RegEx.

Comment: Tip: Use the code generator: https://regex101.com/r/lKpn6k/2/codegen?language=javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `g` modifier, without it you can get matching groups:

```js
var url = 'https://example.com/eb5f16e5-9b3d-cfcd-19b0-75c6ace724e1/size/80x90/center/';
var res = url.match(/\/(\d+)x(\d+)\//);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

`RegExp#exec` will return all the captured group including the captured subexpression.

```js
var url = 'https://example.com/eb5f16e5-9b3d-cfcd-19b0-75c6ace724e1/size/80x90/center/';
var patt = /\/(\d+)x(\d+)\//g;
var result = [];
while ((result = patt.exec(url)) !== null) {
  console.log(result);
}
```